# Getting PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR when accessing Sandbox environment using PayPal iOS SDK 2.8.4

Tags: ios, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm getting this error when accessing the sandbox environment using PayPal iOS SDK 2.8.4:

> PAYMENT_CREATION_ERROR - There was a problem setting up this payment. Please visit the PayPal website to check your account.

It is working fine for `PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork`, but I'm unable to login using `PayPalEnvironmentSandbox`.

Comment: It seems like account related issues, make sure you have credentials set right